# Why playwright miss pattern url?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I need to handle request with certain url and im trying to do it like this:

```py
await page.route("**/api/common/v1/play?**", handle_data_route)
```

But it also handles a url like this: `api/common/v1/play_random?`

Comment: I believe the final `?` character is being treated as part of the regular expression rather than a literal `?` character

Comment: @Souperman but in doesnt look like regular expression at all. I tried escaping this character as in regular expressions, then it doesn't work at all

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression instead of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a regular expression instead

```
await page.route(/^.*\/api\/common\/v1\/play\?.*$/, handle_data_route)
```